# Ruby missing taglib error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, taglib

On my Ubuntu 14.04 I installed Ruby 2.2.0 using RVM.
I have installed the "taglib" using following command `sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev`.

However when I try to install a gem I get the following error:

```
> gem install stream2tracks
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing stream2tracks:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/dash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0-dev/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150207-2313-h67sa7.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for taglib/tag_c.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/dash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0-dev/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/dash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-dev/gems/taglib2-0.1.5 for inspection.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `libtagc0-dev` to get TagLib's C header (the one the gem is checking for).